# Stackedbars on jqPlot with a dynamic json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jqplot

I've been trying to accomplish a chart on jqPlot using the stacked bars (imho, there would be a better way to graphically display the data above, but thats not up to me.)
so heres the dummy data:

```
var data = {
                    "Network 1": {
                        "Avg. Speed": 10000,
                        "D/S": 10000,
                        "U/S": 10000
                    },
                    "Network 2": {
                        "Avg. Speed": 15000,
                        "D/S": 15000,
                        "U/S": 15000
                    },
                    "Network 3": {
                        "Avg. Speed": 20000,
                        "D/S": 20000,
                        "U/S": 20000
                    }
                };
```

Network's would be the X axis and the Avg. Speed/ DS and US would be the facts so each network would have, in this case 3 stacked bars with their data.

I've been passing jqplot data like this just to check the results but, the graph is blank:

```
plot2 = $.jqplot('divGraphNetwork', [], {
        animate: !$.jqplot.use_excanvas,
        stackSeries: true,
        dataRenderer: data,
        seriesDefaults: {
            renderer: $.jqplot.BarRenderer,
            rendererOptions: {
                barPadding: 2,
                barMargin: 0,
                barDirection: 'vertical',
                barWidth: 20
            },
            pointLabels: {
                //location: 'se',
                ypadding: 0
            }
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Network Information',   // title for the plot,
            show: true,
        },
        legend: {
            show: false,
            location: 'e',
            placement: 'outside'
        },
        axes: {
            xaxis: {
                renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer
            },
            yaxis: {
                min:0,
                autoscale: true
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dataRenderer` should be a function not a JSON object. This function should take the JSON object and convert it to a 2D array.

The 2D array should be in the following format:

```
[[Network1 AV/Speed, Network2 AV/Speed, Network3 AV/Speed],
[Network1 D/S, Network2 D/S, Network3 D/S],
[Network1 U/S, Network2 U/S, Network3 U/S]]
```

I've created a Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/dH7Hm/71/) to demonstrate. I've added a `dataRenderer()` function as follows:

```
function dataRenderer() {
    var result = [];
    var avgSpeed = [];
    var ds = [];
    var us = [];
    // Loop over each network
    for (var network in data) {
        // Add each of the stats for the network into the corresponding array
        avgSpeed.push(data[network]["Avg. Speed"]);
        ds.push(data[network]["D/S"]);
        us.push(data[network]["U/S"]);
    }
    // Add the av speed, DS and US arrays to the result array creating a 2D array
    result.push(avgSpeed);
    result.push(ds);
    result.push(us)
    return result;
}
```

I've then modified the dataRenderer option to point to the function instead of the JSON object data:

```
var plot2 = $.jqplot('divGraphNetwork', [], {
    ...
    dataRenderer: dataRenderer,
    ....
});
```

Comment: Datarenderer allows a variable also, I've solved in a similar way but thats the best answer!
Thanks